# Normalization csv file by Encog C#

Tags: normalization, encog

I don't know how to normalize a csv file by using Encog C#..My csv data file:

7.7,3.8,6.7,2.2,\n
7.7,2.6,6.9,2.3,\n
6,2.2,5,1.5,6.9,\n

Comment: @VedaadShakib... admittedly the question was poorly written but here's no need to be mean!

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I'm just pointing out that this question does not adhere to the standards that StackOverflow currently maintains: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service where users can simply request a piece of code to be written for them; it is a site in which experts offers assistance to their peers regarding problems or suggestions in their already-existing code. It is not fair to the rest of the community to have beginner programmers simply expecting us to write their code for them.

Comment: @VedaadShakib everyone has to start somewhere though right? If someone doesn't know where to begin it can be tough. He's not asking someone to write a whole program for him... just for some advice on how to normalize a CSV file. I had the function in my code so I just copied it here for him... wasn't too much hassle. I don't feel like I've been unfairly treated. Are there some official guidelines for S.O. questions?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign This site is not for people who want to learn programming. If you want to learn, go read a book. There are no official guidelines, but there are accepted standards that the community upholds. If you're interested in learning about them, I suggest you look on meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @VedaadShakib I will take a look at meta.stackexchange as you suggest. I don't think he's learning to code here... rather learning to use a specific function of specific library. Although there are other examples out there. I think the real issue is that he hasn't bothered to write a detailed question demonstrating what he's tried so far.

Comment: @VedaadShakib I was looking at meta exchange but I am unable to find a reference to the standards that you mentioned. Could you please provide me with a link for further reading?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I agree with you in regards to the issue with his question. I searched up "good stackoverflow question" on google and got http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I also found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question and http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#stackoverflow.

Comment: @VedaadShakib... Nice one! I Will have a read... hopefully will help me to minimize my down-votes.

Answer (score 1):

Here http://www.heatonresearch.com/comment/2690#comment-2690  there's an answer to your question. I hope that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice function to do it... of course you need to create an analyst

```
    private EncogAnalyst _analyst;

    public void NormalizeFile(FileInfo SourceDataFile, FileInfo NormalizedDataFile)
    {
        var wizard = new AnalystWizard(_analyst);
        wizard.Wizard(SourceDataFile, _useHeaders, AnalystFileFormat.DecpntComma);
        var norm = new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
        norm.Analyze(SourceDataFile, _useHeaders, CSVFormat.English, _analyst);
        norm.ProduceOutputHeaders = _useHeaders;
        norm.Normalize(NormalizedDataFile);
    }
```